# A question related to (odd) perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functional-inequalities, perfect-numbers

In what follows, I will let $\sigma$ denote the classical sum-of-divisors function.

> Example: $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=12$

Let us call a number $x \in \mathbb{N}$ *perfect* if $\sigma(x)=2x$.

Let $M=(2^p - 1)\cdot{2^{p-1}}$ be an *even* perfect number.

Notice that $\sigma(2^p - 1) = 2^p$ and $\sigma(2^{p-1}) = 2^p - 1$ are both deficient numbers.

Now, let $N={q^k}{n^2}$ be an *odd* perfect number.

Here is my question:

> Is it possible to prove that both $\sigma(q^k)$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ are deficient?

Here is my attempt:

> Since $$\sigma(N)=\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=2N=2{q^k}{n^2}$$
>   and $N$ is perfect, then it follows that $\frac{1}{2}\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)$ is perfect.  Since $2 \nmid \sigma(n^2)$, this implies that $\sigma(n^2)$ is deficient since it is a factor of the (odd) perfect number $N=\frac{1}{2}\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)$.

Now how about $\sigma(q^k)$?  The most that I could prove is that $\frac{1}{2}\sigma(q^k)$ is deficient.  (I am currently unable to prove, for example, that $\sigma(\sigma(q^k))<2\sigma(q^k)$.)

> I could only prove though, that $$3/2 < \sigma(\sigma(q^k))/\sigma(q^k) \leq 3,$$
>   using $$a\sigma(b) \leq \sigma(ab) \leq \sigma(a)\sigma(b)$$
>   which holds for all $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Since $(q + 1) \nmid N$, we are not even sure if $\sigma(q^k)$ is deficient for $k = 1$.